# Hook into \input (or any underlying command) in order to allow transparent preprocessing

Tags: macros, packages, input

Which command would be most suitable to be hooked in order to *preprocess* input before it is passed to TeX?

Input file:

```
\begin{document}
    \input{a}
\end{document}
```

Seen by TeX (after a file `a_pp.tex` has been created):

```
\begin{document}
    \input{a_pp}
\end{document}
```

What about `\include`, `\bibliography`, or even other means of including files?

Note that the preprocessing is to be applied only to files that are interpreted/compiled by TeX directly, not to files that are read and parsed by some macro.

This is to move towards 
[Forward-inverse search using SyncTeX with the precison of a single word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39678/8057).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`filehook`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/filehook) package gives you the options to do something at the beginning or end of each `\input` and `\include`.

For instance you could use `\AtBeginEveryFile` to have some arbitrary code called
whenever a file is included.

Comment: You should thank Martin Scharrer who wrote the package!

Comment: True. It is so much easier to use packages that define a clear interface for a certain aspects, than having to delve into TeX internals. Thanks a lot, @MartinScharrer!