# Macros and environments that rely on the distinction between space and newline

Tags: macros, catcodes, big-list

In most cases, TeX does not distinguish between spaces and newlines. However, inside some macros and environments this distinction matters a lot. Time for a big list? Please edit the CW answer.

This occurred when pondering about [Forward-inverse search using SyncTeX with the precison of a single word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39678/8057); this "expert knowledge" is however also relevant for any tool that tries to preprocess (La)TeX code, such as `latexdiff`.

Comment: As everyone can define its own verbatim-like environment e.g. with the help of `fancyvrb` or `listings` I don't see how you should ever been able to get a complete list.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes, indeed this adds even more complexity. But still not impossible, just makes the list bigger and... *dynamic* :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Environments

- `verbatim`
- `lstlisting`, plus custom environments defined through `\lstnewenvironment`  (`listings` package)
- `Verbatim`, plus custom environments defined through `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment` (`fancyvrb` package)

## Commands

- `\index`
- `\verb`
- `\obeylines`