# Override synctex position

Tags: forward-inverse-search

How can I override or “fake” a synctex position?

Let's say we have a file `foo.tex`, where we define a command:

```
%% foo.tex
\newcommand{\foo}{Very much content here}
```

and a file bar.tex, where the command is used:

```
%% bar.tex
\foo
```

In this case synctex would jump to `bar.tex`, but I want it to jump to foo.tex.

Is there any possibility to create a command `\setSynctexPosition` that means something like “synctex, please synchronize me with the file foo.tex”, like this:

```
%% foo.tex
\newcommand{\foo}{%
  \setSynctexPosition{foo.tex}{line 3}%
  Very much content here%
}
```

Can this be done at all, for example by appending some text to the `.synctex` file with, e.g., `\immediate\write18{echo '<some synctex commands>' >> \jobname.synctex}`?

Comment: Background:
While some people even [want synctex to be accurate on word level](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39678/50960), in my case it is not even accurate on file level, because I am using a package which stores content in an auxiliary file and outputs it much later.
This way, synctex synchronizes with the auxiliary file (which is also barely readable) and not with the actual content.

Comment: SyncTeX works independently of TeX's `\write` streams and, as far as I know, there is no way for interacting with it from the user's level, because it works at the level where lists are transformed into boxes.

Comment: Can I enter this level somehow (without recompiling latex)?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution, which is surprisingly easy!

For the sake of completeness:

```
%% bar.tex
\documentclass{article}
\input{foo}
\begin{document}
    \foo
\end{document}
```

And the solution:

```
%% foo.tex
\ifdefined\fakesynctexhelper\fakesynctexhelper\fi%% Does nothing at the beginning, helps later

\newcommand{\foo}{%
    {%% group, so that if will not be defined later anymore
        \def\fakesynctexhelper{%
            Very much content here%% The actual desired content of \foo
            %
            \endinput%% Stop processing the file again
        }%
        \input{foo}%% input this file, so that the synctex information is updated.
    }%
}
```

At the beginning of `foo.tex`, a helper command is run if it's defined.
In the command `\foo` we define the helper command to do what `\foo` should do and call the file `foo.tex`, where this command is expanded at the beginning, so that synctex knows/thinks that `foo.tex` is processed.
Additionally, the helper command is set up to stop further processing of the file `foo.tex`, so that it's original content is not processed again.

Comment: Yes that works, Scz, however it seems to cause synctex to point to this line: \ifdefined\fakesynctexhelper\fakesynctexhelper\fi rather than this one: Very much content here If we could make it point to the content, that would be great.

Comment: In LuaTeX it's possible to do something like `tex.set_synctex_line(10) tex.set_synctex_mode(2)`. Documentation is a little sparse, however.