# Is the pdfsync package still relevant?

Tags: forward-inverse-search, obsolete, pdfsync

I just got a bug report for `multicol` because of a strange white space at the top of the first column and I traced it to the use of the `pdfsync` package that added material in various places that did somehow conflict with the column balancing routines of `multicol`.

Now this is rather an issue with this particular package that adds material in a way it perhaps shouldn't (well it warns that this could happen and that it should never be used on final documents). But it makes me wonder **if there are any useful applications for this package at all these days**, given that you can get this functionality (at least with TL binaries) by specifying `-synctex=1` and use editors like TeXWorks  without any side-effects.

If the answer is yes it is needed, which are those applications? If no, shouldn't the package get a bold warning (say, via `\typeout`) that it would be better to remove it and rely on a different approach?

Even if the answer is yes, I think a `\typeout`warning would be in order that it shouldn't be used on final documents (as the author states).

Comment: I think that the answer is a clear "don't use `pdfsync` for any reason whatsoever".

Comment: Here's a relevant question: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/73415/stretched-columns-when-trying-to-color-individual-cells

Comment: those who agree may upvote @egreg's comment and/or the answer below. Anybody with a real usecase for the package .. please share as an answer or comment!

Comment: This question looks in fact as a dup of http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4491/1340

Comment: Spot on @egreg (I wish I had read this in 2012). Make sure you also clean up all pdfsync garbage as it will get in the way of synctex.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had a stupendous mess trying to use `pdfsync` in combination with `ledmac`-`ledpar`. It seems that something in `pdfsync` interferes with the columns or parallel pages settings. Thus, my recomendation would be at least to add a warning of not using the package in combination with `multicol`, `ledpar` and similar packages.

Comment: ok, looks like there is consensus that (at least these days) this particular package should be avoided as it will produce problems and there are cleaner ways nowadays that avoid this. So I'll accept this as (the only) answer.

Answer (score 3):

This is a supplement to [Anabel's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71429/). The package documentation for the last update of `pdfsync` states:

> This is most certainly the last update of this package, this
>   technology will most certainly be embedded in pdfTEX and XETEX engines
>   and won’t rely any longer on pdf techniques. As a matter of fact,
>   synchronization will be available both for dvi, xdv and pdf. Also it
>   will work the same for Plain, L A TEX, ConTEXt and whatsoever.
>   Moreover, synchronization will not modify any package.