# Stretched columns when trying to color individual cells

Tags: tables, color, pdfsync

I'm trying to make a time plan for a project using tables in LaTeX but I've run into a small problem. The table below will look fine until I try to colour individual cells by adding `\usepackage[table,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}`. Doing this will stretch the middle column all the way out to the right edge of the paper. It does this even without me adding the `\cellcolor{somecolor}` command or making any other alterations to the table.

Here's a little bit more elaborate example than was originally posted:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm,vmargin=2cm,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hang,small,bf]{caption}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[table,usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}


% Document start
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\begin{center}

\end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\section*{Time plan}

\noindent X\dotfill X

\noindent\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{r p{8cm} @{\extracolsep{\fill}} l}
\toprule
Week & Task & Date \\
\midrule
37 &\cellcolor{yellow} Project start & 2012-09-13 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\pagebreak

\end{document}
```

And here's what it looks like:

[image]

I have seriously no idea of what's going on here so any help would be much appreciated! It might be worth pointing out that I'm also using the `multirow` package, if that has any impact on making coloring work. All packages seems to be up to date.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: I don't get that output.

Comment: @egreg I do get that output, on the top of the second page. TeXLive 2012, PDFTeX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick to making a good MWE is to keep removing packages that are not used by the example until the problem goes away. In this case

```
\usepackage{pdfsync}
```

is the tipping point. This presumably adds some whatsit nodes to enable the sync to happen that are messing up the colortbl spacing.

Comment: Sorry for not responding until now but: wow, thanks! It worked! :)