# Multicols: How to center two cols?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, enumerate, multicol

I'm sorry by my poor English. Thanks for any help. 
Here is my question:

I would like to center two expressions by using the multicols and enumerate commands, just like this: 
[image]

Unfortunately the command I am using is producing this:
[image]

Here is my commands:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\pr}{\hspace*{1.5cm}}
\newcommand{\sen}{{\mbox{sen\,}}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\senh}{senh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsen}{arcsen}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{arctg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cotg}{cotg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccotg}{arccotg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsec}{arcsec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cossec}{cossec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccossec}{arccossec}



\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myheadings} \thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
        \item $f (x) = \begin{cases}
        \ds x\sen\dfrac{1}{x}, & \hbox{ se } x \neq 0\\
        0, & \hbox{ se } x = 0
        \end{cases} $ \quad \quad
        \item $f (x) = \begin{cases}
        \ds x^2\sen\dfrac{1}{x}, & \hbox{ se } x \neq 0\\
        0, & \hbox{ se } x = 0
        \end{cases} $
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I'm sorry, I could not explain it right. Items (a) and (b) I would like to be centered and aligned horizontally on the same line, like that de first figure. Item (b) is higher than item (a) (the second figure).

Comment: You want to centre each  expression w.r.t. what?

Comment: Could you show a complete example and not only some fragment? What class are you using? how is `\ds` defined? ...

Comment: \ds is \displaystyle and \sen is \sin (in portuguese)

Comment: ,@Moura - The problem can be solved at a glance, but without giving the required information about your real document setup (class, single/double column, commands before/after ...) you are unlikely to get any good answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  `tasks` environment is done for that, as the numbering will be from left to right first, then vertical, whereas `multicol` does the converse. I took the opportunity to correct your code: nowadays, the language option from `babel` should be loaded as an option of the document class. Note `amscd` should be replaced with `tikz-cd`, as it yields better results.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, brazil, 12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amscd, bezier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tasks}

\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\pr}{\hspace*{1.5cm}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\sen}{sen}
\DeclareMathOperator{\senh}{senh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsen}{arcsen}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{arctg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cotg}{cotg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccotg}{arccotg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsec}{arcsec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cossec}{cossec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccossec}{arccossec}

\begin{document}

\pagestyle{myheadings} \thispagestyle{empty}
    \begin{tasks}(2)
        \task $f (x) = \begin{cases}
        \ds x\sen\dfrac{1}{x}, & \hbox{ se } x \neq 0\\
        0, & \hbox{ se } x = 0
        \end{cases} $ %\quad \quad
        \task $f (x) = \begin{cases}
        \ds x^2\sen\dfrac{1}{x}, & \hbox{ se } x \neq 0\\
        0, & \hbox{ se } x = 0
        \end{cases} $
    \end{tasks}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Now that you have provided the real setup with used packages, I can confirm that the real cause of this white space above the first column is due to the `pdfsync` package. It somehow conflicts with the column balancing routines of `multicol`. As @egreg once said: ["don't use pdfsync for any reason whatsoever"](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70820/is-the-pdfsync-package-still-relevant/215881#comment152788_70820). Also, `\quad \quad` is meaningless here, just remove it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amscd,bezier}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{pdfsync}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{multicol}

\newcommand{\ds}{\displaystyle}
\newcommand{\pr}{\hspace*{1.5cm}}
\newcommand{\sen}{{\mbox{sen\,}}}

\DeclareMathOperator{\senh}{senh}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsen}{arcsen}
\DeclareMathOperator{\tg}{tg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arctg}{arctg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cotg}{cotg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccotg}{arccotg}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arcsec}{arcsec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\cossec}{cossec}
\DeclareMathOperator{\arccossec}{arccossec}  

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{myheadings} \thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{multicols}{2}
    \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
        \item $f (x) = \begin{cases}
        \ds x\sen\dfrac{1}{x}, & \hbox{ se } x \neq 0\\
        0, & \hbox{ se } x = 0
        \end{cases} $ %\quad \quad
        \item $f (x) = \begin{cases}
        \ds x^2\sen\dfrac{1}{x}, & \hbox{ se } x \neq 0\\
        0, & \hbox{ se } x = 0
        \end{cases} $
    \end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is the problem \usepackage{pdfsync} ? 
It is working now. Thanks a lot