# using my university latex template

Tags: pdftex

I have my university thesis template but having trouble running it. I'm running it using TexShop in my Mac(OS X). Here's the template:

```
\documentclass[oneside,final, letterpaper]{ucr}
\begin{document}

% Declarations for Front Matter

\title{The title goes here}
\author{John Joe Smith}
\degreemonth{December}
\degreeyear{2009}
\degree{Doctor of Philosophy}
\chair{Professor Michael Jordan}
\chairtwo{Professor Kobe Bryant}
\othermembers{Professor LeBron James}
\numberofmembers{3}
\field{Computer Science}
\campus{Riverside}

\maketitle
\copyrightpage{}
\approvalpage{}

\degreesemester{Fall}

\begin{frontmatter}

\begin{acknowledgements}
I am grateful to my advisor, without whose help, I would not have been here.
\end{acknowledgements}

\begin{dedication}
\null\vfil
{\large
\begin{center}
To my parents for all the support.
\end{center}}
\vfil\null
\end{dedication}

\input{abstract}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\end{frontmatter}

% \part{First Part}


\input{chapter1} %usually intro
\input{chapter2}
\input{chapter3}
\input{chapter4}
\input{conclusions}



\nocite{*}
% \singlespacing
% \bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibfile}

\input{appendix}


\end{document}
```

When I try running it, I get 2 errors:
! LaTeX Error: File `pdfsync.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or  to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

! LaTeX Error: File `fncylab.sty' not found.

I tried changing the typesetting to Pdf Sync but still get these errors. As far as this package is concerned, the package documentation on CTAN says that it is the same as the graphics.sty. I also tried inserting these 2 packages while running the template but still doesn't help. So, I'm not sure what is actually missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I take it ucr.cls was provided by the University of California, Riverside?  How would one go about obtaining a copy?  Most of the macros used in you MWE are nonstandard.

Comment: I started out using my university's thesis class, but quickly found that it was out of date and wasted a lot of time trying to figure out what exactly the .cls file did. I ended up making my own preamble from stuff I learned on tex.se

Answer (score 3):

I downloaded the PhD latex template *.zip file.  Then I extracted it into a folder. Now using TeXmaker (any IDE or OS should work) I ran pdflatex twice and then viewed it.  It compiles successfully. So:

1) Verify that you have a folder with:

```
 Directory of ..\ucthesisPhDTwoChairs
03/11/2009  02:25 PM             6,148 .DS_Store
10/20/2015  02:09 PM                 0 dir.txt
03/10/2009  04:51 PM               362 sw20uctd.sty
03/10/2009  04:51 PM               581 thmsupp.tex
03/12/2009  09:59 AM            47,995 ucr.cls
03/10/2009  04:51 PM            18,341 uct10.clo
03/10/2009  04:51 PM            18,374 uct11.clo
03/10/2009  04:51 PM            18,431 uct12.clo
10/20/2015  02:06 PM             5,634 uctest.tex
```

2) Verify that you have a current and properly updated LaTeX distribution installed on your computer.

Then when the template provided WITHOUT ANY changes runs, you can now begin to personalize the template.

Comment: Though the template may work with a full TeX distribution, [pdfsync is deprecated](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4491/what-is-the-status-of-pdfsync).