# Shade cell of table without using colortbl

Tags: tables, color

I have a table which I want to shade certain cells of. I know this is simple to do using colortbl and xcolor, but the colortbl package conflicts with another package I am using (OTtablx). Is there any other way to shade table cells? Or, alternatively, is there a way to turn off the conflicting package just for this table and then turn it back on?

OTtablx (which "makes heavy use of PSTricks, which precludes direct use of pdfLATEX to generate PDFs", if that is relevant) makes tables easily in a special format particular to my discipline. I use these throughout this document and can't change them now. I don't care that I can't shade those special tables, I just have one regular table I want to put shading in. My current workaround is to make it in word, take a screenshot, convert to .eps in photoshop, and put it in with \includegraphics. Ugly, ugly, ugly.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[top=1.375in,left=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,headheight=.25in,headsep=.2in]{geometry}

\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for much better looking tables
\usepackage{multirow, multicol}

%\usepackage{tipa} %included in OTtablx, don't need to load separately unless you need to use options
\usepackage [medium] {OTtablx} %must run with tex and dvi not pdftex

\newcommand{\0}{$\emptyset$} %null


\begin{document}
Here is a plain, unshaded table.
\begin{table}[h]
{\begin{threeparttable}\caption{Agreement paradigms}\label{table:comboagree}
\centering
\fontsize{10.5}{12}\selectfont
  \begin{tabular}{ r l l@{}r lr@{\extracolsep{1em}}l@{}r l@{}r@{\extracolsep{1em}}l@{}r l@{}r }
\toprule
&&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Indicative}}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Optative}}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Negative}}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{14}{l}{{A. OBJECT AGREEMENT}}\\[0.5ex]
\textbf{Obj} & \textbf{Subj} &\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}\\
\cmidrule{3-6}\cmidrule{7-10}\cmidrule{11-14}
1s\phantom{} & &    na-&&kana-&\phantom{-i}&    na-&-i&kana-&-i&    na-&-ara&kana-&-ap\\
1pl & &         kin-&&&&                    kin-&-i&&&      kin-&-ap&&\\
2s\phantom{} & &    i-&-ap&&&                   i-&-ap&&&           \0-&-ap&&\\
2pl & &         kii(k)-&-ap&&&              kii(k)-&-ap&&&      kii(k)-&-ap&&\\
[0.5ex]\midrule
\multicolumn{14}{l}{{B. SUBJECT AGREEMENT}}\\[0.5ex]
\textbf{Subj} & \textbf{Obj} &\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}\\
\cmidrule{3-6}\cmidrule{7-10}\cmidrule{11-14}
    &\textbf{2nd}&  &&&&&&&&&&\\
1\phantom{} & & nu-&\phantom{-i}&n/a&&      nu-&-i&n/a&&        kin-&-ara&n/a&\\[0.5ex]
    &\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{3rd/intransitive}}&     &&&&            &&&\\
1s\phantom{} & &    ni-&&&&                 kan-&-i&&&      na-&-ara&&\\
2s\phantom{} & &    i-&&&&                  \0-&-i&&&           \0-&-ara&&\\
3s\phantom{} & &    u-&&&&                  kam-&-i&&&      \0-&-ara&\0-&-ap\\
1pl & &         nu-&&&&                 nu-&-i&&&           kin-&-ara&&\\
2pl & &         ku-&&&&                 kii(k)-&-i&&&       \0-&-ap&&\\
3pl & &         kun-&&kin-&\phantom{-i}&        kun-&-i&kin-&-i&    \0-&-ap&kin-&-ap\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 \begin{tablenotes} 
  \small
  \item[a] Unless marked \textit{n/a}, when no entry is given in the plural column, the agreement affixes listed in the singular colum apply for both singular and plural.
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}}
\end{table}
\normalsize


%And just for reference, here is the code for a table produced by OTtablx.
%
%\begin{OTtableau}{5}
%   \OTsolids{3,4,5}\OTdashes{1,2}
%   \OTtoprow    [/avansa/] { {\sc Max-C}, {\sc *CC-Coda}, {\sc Dep}, {*V\#},{\sc Max-V}}
%   \OTcandrow {avan} {*!,,,,*}
%   \OTcandrow {avans} {,*!,,,*}
%   \OTcandrow [\OThand] {avansa} {,,,*,}
%\end{OTtableau}

\end{document}
```

Here is a picture of what I want the table to look like (I don't know how to do the annotations, either, but shading is my top priority):
[image: desired shading]

edited to add: Here are pictures of what it normally looks like, and what happens to the OTtablx when I load colortbl (or array) in the actual document. This does not occur in the MWE, and I have no idea why.

[image: normal OTtablx]

[image: first cell in OTtablx running off right margin]

Comment: Well if it helps, you could just typeset the table as a separate latex document, compile it to postscript, crop the borders with `ps2eps`, and include that as a graphic. In this way, you easily get the same fonts etc. that you also use in the main document.

Comment: That sounds promising, but I don't have the first idea how to go about doing that. I use TexShop to typeset using LaTeX with script set to Tex + DVI, and I just push the button and it compiles everything and outputs a pdf. I have several separate .tex files I am combining using \include, with only one preamble in the root .tex file.

Comment: Instead of showing us the exact table you want, can you show a minimal example that demonstrates how `OTtablx` conflicts with `colortbl` and maybe we can solve that problem.

Comment: @largercat - Alan's advice is good, I would suggest trying that first. As to my own suggestion, you just create a separate latex document for the table. You use the same preamble as for the main document, except that you now load `colortbl` instead of `OTtblx`. Add `\pagestyle{empty}` to the preamble, and put everything from `\begin{threeparttable}` to `\end{threeparttable}` inside the document (and nothing else). Then, compile it as you are won't to do. Ctd. ...

Comment: Just to be clear, your example document works with `colortbl` with no problem.

Comment: ... Since you are compiling to pdf, you must convert that to eps. Open a shell window and navigate to your working directory. Run `pdftops mytable.pdf` - this should give you a .ps version of your .pdf file. Then run `ps2eps mytable.ps`, which should give you the .eps version that you can include with `\includegraphics`.

Comment: You are totally right @Alan, the OT tableau does work with colortbl in the MWE I gave, embarassed I didn't check that. There must be something else causing it to go off in the actual document. I will add what happens.

Comment: Oh, wow, I added back in my entire preamble, line by line, and the conflicting package was pdfsync. But only with both these other packages together! Please advise how I should edit the question to make this useful (I am new to this). Also the shading and annotations in the answers look fantastic and I will see if I can use them, this conflict problem aside, when I have a minute.

Comment: @largercat `pdfsync` is now part of the standard engines, and should not be used anyway. See [What is the status of pdfsync](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4491/2693) (Only 7 years ago...) Problem solved? :)

Comment: Yes, problem solved! And yes, there are some things in my preamble inherited from that long ago. Cleaning it up bit by bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can compile with `xelatex` and call the `table` option with the document class options, which will call `colortbl`. It compiles fine.

It also compiles almost fine with `pdflatex`, if you load `auto-pst-pdf`  (to be loaded *after* `pstricks` and if you add the `-shell-escape` switch to the compiler). *Almost* because the `OTtableau` is not displayed, as it requires a true type font for which I have no support (so, unrelated to pstricks/colortbl).

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside, table, svgnames]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=1.375in,left=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,headheight=.25in,headsep=.2in]{geometry}

\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for much better looking tables
\usepackage{multirow, multicol}

%\usepackage{tipa} %included in OTtablx, don't need to load separately unless you need to use options
\usepackage [medium] {OTtablx} %must run with tex and dvi not pdftex
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand\greycell{\cellcolor{Gainsboro!70}}
\newcommand{\0}{$\emptyset$} %null
%\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
Here is a plain, unshaded table.
\begin{table}[h]
{\begin{threeparttable}\caption{Agreement paradigms}\label{table:comboagree}
\centering
\fontsize{10.5}{12}\selectfont
  \begin{tabular}{ r l l@{}r lr@{\extracolsep{1em}}l@{}r l@{}r@{\extracolsep{1em}}l@{}r l@{}r }
\toprule
&&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Indicative}}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Optative}}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Negative}}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{14}{l}{{A. OBJECT AGREEMENT}}\\[0.5ex]
\textbf{Obj} & \textbf{Subj}
&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}\\
\cmidrule{3-6}\cmidrule{7-10}\cmidrule{11-14}
1s\phantom{} & & na-&&kana-&\phantom{-i}& na-&-i&kana-&-i& na-&-ara&kana-&-ap\\
1pl & & kin-&&&& kin-&-i&&& kin-&-ap&&\\
2s\phantom{} & & \greycell i- &\multicolumn{3}{>{\greycell}l}{-ap} & \greycell i- & \multicolumn{3}{>{\columncolor{Gainsboro!70}[12pt][6pt]}l}{-ap} & \greycell \0- & \multicolumn{3}{>{\columncolor{Gainsboro!70}[12pt][6pt]}l}{-ap}\\
2pl & & \greycell kii(k)-&\multicolumn{3}{>{\greycell}l}{-ap} & \greycell kii(k)-& \multicolumn{3}{>{\columncolor{Gainsboro!70}[12pt][6pt]}l}{-ap}& \greycell kii(k)- & \multicolumn{3}{>{\columncolor{Gainsboro!70}[12pt][6pt]}l}{-ap} \\
[0.5ex]\midrule
\multicolumn{14}{l}{{B. SUBJECT AGREEMENT}}\\[0.5ex]
\textbf{Subj} & \textbf{Obj}
&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}\\
\cmidrule{3-6}\cmidrule{7-10}\cmidrule{11-14}
    &\textbf{2nd}& &&&&&&&&&&\\
1\phantom{} & & \greycell nu- &\greycell \phantom{-i}& n/a&& nu-&-i&n/a&& kin-&-ara&n/a&\\[0.5ex]
    &\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{3rd/intransitive}}& &&&& &&&\\
1s\phantom{} & & \multicolumn{4}{>{\greycell}l}{ni-} & kan-&-i&&& na-&-ara&&\\
2s\phantom{} & & \multicolumn{4}{>{\greycell}l}{i-} & \0-&-i&&& \0-&-ara&&\\
3s\phantom{} & & \multicolumn{4}{>{\greycell}l}{u-} & kam-&-i&&& \0-&-ara&\0-&-ap\\
1pl & & \multicolumn{4}{>{\greycell}l}{nu-} & nu-&-i & & & kin-&-ara & &\\
2pl & & \multicolumn{4}{>{\greycell}l}{ku-}& \greycell kii(k)- & \multicolumn{3}{>{\columncolor{Gainsboro!70}[12pt][6pt]}l}{-i}& \0-&-ap&&\\
3pl & & \multicolumn{2}{>{\greycell}l}{kun-} &kin-&\phantom{-i}& \greycell kun- & \greycell -i&kin-&-i& \0-&-ap&kin-&-ap\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
 \begin{tablenotes}
  \small
  \item[a] Unless marked \textit{n/a}, when no entry is given in the plural column, the agreement affixes listed in the singular colum apply for
      both singular and plural.
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}}
\end{table}
\normalsize

And just for reference, here is the code for a table produced by OTtablx.

\begin{OTtableau}{5}
 \OTsolids{3,4,5}\OTdashes{1,2}
 \OTtoprow [/avansa/] { {\sc Max-C}, {\sc *CC-Coda}, {\sc Dep}, {*V\#},{\sc Max-V}}
 \OTcandrow {avan} {*!,,,,*}
 \OTcandrow {avans} {,*!,,,*}
 \OTcandrow [\OThand] {avansa} {,,,*,}
\end{OTtableau}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As Bernard says in his answer, compiling with XeLaTeX will do what you want. It also allows you to add annotations to the table using TikZ:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[top=1.375in,left=1in,right=1in,bottom=1in,headheight=.25in,headsep=.2in]{geometry}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{threeparttablex}
\usepackage{booktabs} % for much better looking tables
\usepackage{multirow, multicol}

%\usepackage{tipa} %included in OTtablx, don't need to load separately unless you need to use options
\usepackage [medium] {OTtablx} %must run with tex and dvi not pdftex
\newcommand{\cgr}{\cellcolor[gray]{.90}}
\newcommand{\0}{$\emptyset$} %null
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,shapes.geometric,decorations.pathreplacing,calc}
\newcommand\tikzmk[1]{\tikz[remember picture,overlay]\node (#1) {};}

\begin{document}
Here is a plain, unshaded table.
\begin{table}[h]
{\begin{threeparttable}\caption{Agreement paradigms}\label{table:comboagree}
\centering
\fontsize{10.5}{12}\selectfont
  \begin{tabular}{ r l l@{}r lr@{\extracolsep{1em}}l@{}r l@{}r@{\extracolsep{1em}}l@{}r l@{}r }
\toprule
&&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Indicative}}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Optative}}&\multicolumn{4}{c}{\textbf{Negative}}\\
\midrule
\multicolumn{14}{l}{{A. OBJECT AGREEMENT}}\\[0.5ex]
\textbf{Obj} & \textbf{Subj} &\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}\\
\cmidrule{3-6}\cmidrule{7-10}\cmidrule{11-14}
1s\phantom{} & &    na-&&kana-&\phantom{-i}&    na-&-i&kana-&-i&    na-&-ara&kana-&-ap\tikzmk{G}\\
1pl & &         kin-&&&&                    kin-&-i&&&      kin-&-ap&&\tikzmk{H}\\
2s\phantom{} &\tikzmk{A} & \cgr i- &\multicolumn{3}{>{\cgr}l}{-ap} & \cgr i- & \multicolumn{3}{>{\columncolor{gray!20}[12pt][6pt]}l}{-ap} & \cgr \0- & \multicolumn{3}{>{\columncolor{gray!20}[12pt][3pt]}l}{-ap}\tikzmk{I}\\
2pl &\hspace*{1cm}\tikzmk{B} & \cgr kii(k)-&\multicolumn{3}{>{\cgr}l}{-ap} & \cgr kii(k)-& \multicolumn{3}{>{\columncolor{gray!20}[12pt][6pt]}l}{-ap}& \cgr kii(k)- & \multicolumn{3}{>{\columncolor{gray!20}[12pt][3pt]}l}{-ap}\tikzmk{J}\\
[0.5ex]\midrule
\multicolumn{14}{l}{{B. SUBJECT AGREEMENT}}\\[0.5ex]
\textbf{Subj} & \textbf{Obj} &\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{s}}&\multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{pl}}\\
\cmidrule{3-6}\cmidrule{7-10}\cmidrule{11-14}
    &\textbf{2nd}&  &&&&&&&&&&\\
1\phantom{} &\tikzmk{C} &\cgr nu-&\phantom{-i}&n/a&&      nu-&-i&n/a&&        kin-&-ara&n/a&\tikzmk{E}\\[0.5ex]
    &\multicolumn{5}{l}{\textbf{3rd/intransitive}}&     &&&&            &&&\\
1s\phantom{} & &\multicolumn{4}{>{\cgr}l}{ni-}&                 kan-&-i&&&      na-&-ara&&\\
2s\phantom{} & &\multicolumn{4}{>{\cgr}l}{i-}&                  \0-&-i&&&           \0-&-ara&&\\
3s\phantom{} & &\multicolumn{4}{>{\cgr}l}{u-}&                  kam-&-i&&&      \0-&-ara&\0-&-ap\\
1pl & &\multicolumn{4}{>{\cgr}l}{nu-}&                 nu-&-i&&&           kin-&-ara&&\\
2pl & &\multicolumn{4}{>{\cgr}l}{ku-}&                 \cgr kii(k)-&-i&&&       \0-&-ap&&\\
3pl &\tikzmk{D} &\cgr         kun-&& kin-&\phantom{-i}&       \cgr kun-&-i& kin-&-i&    \0-&-ap&kin-&-ap\tikzmk{F}\\
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
 \begin{tablenotes} 
  \small
  \item[a] Unless marked \textit{n/a}, when no entry is given in the plural column, the agreement affixes listed in the singular colum apply for both singular and plural.
  \end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\node[draw,fit=(A) (B),font={\scriptsize\scshape},inner sep=0pt,align=center] {inverse};
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt},thick,draw=blue] ($(D)+(20pt,-5pt)$) -- node[pos=.4,rotate=90,yshift=10pt,font=\scriptsize] {non-cohering} ($(C)+(20pt,10pt)$);\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=5pt},thick,draw=blue] ($(E)+(5pt,10pt)$) -- node[midway,rotate=90,yshift=-10pt,font=\scriptsize] {cohering} ($(F)+(5pt,0pt)$);
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt},thick,draw=blue,yshift=2pt] ($(G)+(4pt,5pt)$) -- node[midway,xshift=20pt,font=\scriptsize] {cohering} ($(H)+(4pt,-5pt)$);\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,amplitude=2pt},thick,draw=blue,yshift=2pt] ($(I)+(-2pt,5pt)$) -- node[midway,xshift=20pt,font=\scriptsize,align=center] {non-\\cohering} ($(J)+(-2pt,-5pt)$);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{table}
\normalsize


And just for reference, here is the code for a table produced by OTtablx.

\begin{OTtableau}{5}
   \OTsolids{3,4,5}\OTdashes{1,2}
   \OTtoprow    [/avansa/] { {\sc Max-C}, {\sc *CC-Coda}, {\sc Dep}, {*V\#},{\sc Max-V}}
   \OTcandrow {avan} {*!,,,,*}
   \OTcandrow {avans} {,*!,,,*}
   \OTcandrow [\OThand] {avansa} {,,,*,}
\end{OTtableau}

\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]